# output double in cout C++

Tags: c++, cout

I have problem with my C++ console app when I tried to output `double` that calculate from Vector int it show me `0`

```
for (int i  = 0; i < max_streak_length; i++)
{
    cout<< "data win streak of " << i << " acheived : " << gamesData[i]; 
    cout<< " Propallty \t "<< gamesData[i]/(gamesData[0] + gamesData[1])<<endl;

}
```

output

```
data win streak of 0 acheived : 6 Propallty 0
data win streak of 1 acheived : 5 Propallty 0
data win streak of 2 acheived : 2 Propallty 0
data win streak of 3 acheived : 0 Propallty 0
data win streak of 4 acheived : 0 Propallty 0
data win streak of 5 acheived : 1 Propallty 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your vector contain `double` or `int`s?

It looks like it contains `int`s and if that is the case you need to cast to double:

```
static_cast<double>(gamesData[i])/(gamesData[0] + gamesData[1])
```

When you perform calculations with type `int`, you will always get a result of type `int`.

Comment: (static_cast<double>(gamesData[i]))/(gamesData[0] + gamesData[1])

Answer (score 0):

I think your element type in `gamesData[i]` is `int`. If you want to get the result of `3/2`, the result is 1, for the result of `int/int` is a `int`. If you want to get double data, you need use
`double(gamesData[i])/(gamesData[0] + gamesData[1])` instead. For the type of result depends on the type of numerator in such a situation.